slack custom workflow step response
I am creating simple custom workflow step. I already started receiveing this json https://api.slack.com/events/function_executed from slack when custom step was triggered. Based on docu I responded with status ok 200.
My question is how should i respond or maybe what request should i send that my workflow is already done? What i found out this endpoint is obsolete https://api.slack.com/methods/workflows.stepCompleted
i am seeing what endpoint should i use.
In slack i am still seing that it is in progress:


You’re seeing the workflow steps still marked as "Processing" because Slack hasn’t received a "completed" or "successful" status update for your custom step. In Slack workflows, after receiving the initial trigger and responding with 200 OK, you need to send a POST request to Slack's Functions API to update the status of your workflow step.

@Salt can you point out me to which endpoint i need to send POST request? I still havent found the right one

I found that this is the endpoint i was looking for: https://api.slack.com/methods/functions.completeSuccess
now the workflow step ends in success mode.
